# prevent button press across instances

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I have created a database/app where a report is created when a particular button is clicked. just now, two people managed to hit the button at exactly the same time, which caused all sorts of not-good.

Is there a way to make a button invisible across instances once it's clicked by one person? Or some way to lock the database so nothing can be done until the person who clicked first is done?

I have a solution (basically, a global check variable that stops the report creation) but now I want to know if either of the other two options can be done.

Comment: If by global check variable, you mean updating a value in a table on the network and checking it each time... I believe that's the only of your three methods that would work. Is the report really complicated? If you are only reading the data, which is usually how reports work, there should be no issues. Mind sharing us the code that opens the report and/or the code that generates the report?

Comment: If you have more than one user and your database is not split, reports are going to be the least of your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
    If DLookup("PayLock", "table", "pkID=1") Then 'it's locked - exit
        MsgBox "Someone else has already started the pay process.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    Else
        blah blah blah......
```

The "PayLock" field in the table holds the check variable. After "Else" comes the actual code to run when the button is clicked.

Just FYI, since they were asked:

- it is split database
- there are multiple users
- yes, the report just reads data and exports it into an excel spreadsheet.

It looks like this is the only solution, which works, but seems inelegant. I keep discovering that the way I get around my lack of knowledge is the actual way to do it...

Comment: not-good stuff = paying people more than once, or not at all, or on the wrong account. I do have a method in place for cleaning up bad locks. It still depends on user identification of the problem - my coding isn't so elegant/advanced just yet that I can figure out how to do it automatically. Essentially, when the user IDs a bad lock, they click a button to reset the check variable in the table.

Answer (score 1):

It would really help to know more about your architecture here. What database? What language have you written your application in? Concurrent reading is usually an important and basic feature of most multi-user databases.

Seconding Daniel Cook's general notion, maybe explicating a bit: don't have the button run the report directly. Have it run a little subroutine that first checks a special purpose table where you represent report "runs" with a new record that has a start date-time and an end date-time. If there is a record sitting in the table with no (null) end-date, then the report must still be running, therefore, do NOT begin report, turn off button instead. Else, insert into that same table and then start running the report. Add to this a periodic, not-too-frequent callback on that button to perform the same check, and you've got something that comes close, but isn't "realtime", but should work in most architectures (not knowing anything about session management capabilities).

Comment: Tags give that data: database is Access, language is VBA. What you suggest is what I did, but I was wondering whether there was another way to get around the issue.